# How a component controller works

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, visualforce-component

I am trying to access fname which is set to a value to display in the component . but fname is null. Please see the below code
 Page:

```
    <apex:page >
    <h1>Congratulations Page</h1>
    <c:testcompo ></c:testcompo>  
    </apex:page>
```

Component:

```
    <apex:Component controller="TestCompon">
     <h1>Congratulations {!fname}</h1>
      This is your new Component
    </apex:Component>
```

Controller Class:

```
    public Class TestCompon{
    transient public String fName{
         get {
            return fName;
         }
         set {
           fName ='qsqd1213';
         }    
     }
    }
```

Output:

> Congratulations Page Congratulations Component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really only need to implement an explicit getter and setter method if you have some complex logic or caching to do when the property's value is manipulated, or if there's no underlying storage and the value is calculated at access time.

Here, you can make do with the auto-generated getter and setter that the compiler will generate for you:

```
public String fName { get; set; }
```

That ensures the property can be accessed from Visualforce. Note also that there's no need for this property to be declared `transient`, which means it's not stored in the view state and transmitted back to the server on Visualforce actions.

As written your getter will return the property's value, but your setter will just assign a constant to it. The problem is that your setter is never called, because you don't assign to `fName` elsewhere in your code. Setters aren't initialization functions.

You do, however, need to initialize that value, which you can do in a constructor for your class:

```
public TestCompon() {
     fName = 'Test';
}
```

Note that there's no special syntax for assigning to a property - just treat it like an instance variable.